# Quartz Issue with Camel 3.15.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, quartz

We have recently migrated from spring boot 1.5 to spring boot 2.6.4 and camel 2.X to 3.15.
I've noticed that our persisted jobs stopped working due to

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.pollconsumer.quartz2.QuartzScheduledPollConsumerJob
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
```

As stated in https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3-migration-guide.html we have replaced

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quartz2</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

with

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
     </dependency>
```

quartz properties

```
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
```

I assume the problem is that quartz is looking for a class that now lives under

org.apache.camel.pollconsumer.**quartz**.QuartzScheduledPollConsumerJob

Parts of pom related to spring boot / Camel / Quartz Quartz 2.3, Camel 3.15.0, Spring Boot 2.6.4

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>${quartz.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP-java7</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>${quartz.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-soap</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-csv</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-bindy</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For quartz compatibility of jdbc tirgger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Class for job was stored in db and it was referencing quartz2 package, recreating job table fixed the problem